# Install and Configure XDebug for Netbeans

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

I have been trying to install and configure Xdebug for NetBeans under Windows using the resources on this site: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug. I have not been successful so far.

Could it be the case that I cannot get the correct version of Xdebug for my settings? When I run the Xdebug wizard I get the following information:

> Summary
>
> Xdebug installed: no Server API: CGI/FastCGI Windows: yes - Compiler:
>   MS **VC9** - Architecture: **x86** Zend Server: no PHP Version:
>   **5.5**.7 Zend API nr: 220121212 PHP API nr: 20121212 Debug Build: no Thread Safe Build: **no** Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
>   Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc\php.ini
>   Extensions directory: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext

I guess this means I need to download version PHP 5.5 VC9 (64 bit). The problem is that there is no such version available. There is PHP 5.5 VC11 or PHP 5.4 VC9. Could this be my problem. I just want to be able to debug php. It is so cumbersome to find bugs at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried this? http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: Yes, I copied the output of the wizard in my question above. If I understand the output correctly I need to install xdebug version 5.5 vc9. Unfortunately this version is not available on the website. Hence my question...